# Angularjs UI-Router: How to create view inside nested view? (3 level of nested view)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I am trying to create a view inside a nested view using `UI-Router`

**code**

```
.state('discussions', {
            url: '/discussions',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/groups/groupBaseView.html'
                },
                'leftcontainer@discussions': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/groups/groupView.html',
                    controller: 'groupController',
                    views: {
                        'rightcontainer@leftcontainer@discussions': {
                            template: 'hi'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    });
```

You can visualize the view like

```
--groupBase
--groupBase/groupView
--groupBase/groupView/discussionView
```

the UI is working fine till `--groupBase/groupView` but the `disucussionView` is not getting loaded inside the `groupView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a worknig plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ISiMe6OvXYkbKoJomOCv?p=preview)

**View nesting is possible**, inside of one state. The *state's* **`views: {}`** setting must contain all these views:

```
.state('discussions', {
  url: '/discussions',
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: 'views/groups/groupBaseView.html'
    },
    'leftcontainer@discussions': {
      templateUrl: 'views/groups/groupView.html',
      controller: 'groupController',
    },
    'rightcontainer@discussions': {
      template: '<h3>hi from right container</h3>'
    },
  }

});
```

Having this in place, we can achieve view nesting

- the first view *('views/groups/groupBaseView.html')* is injected into unnamed ui-view inside of the **index.html**
- the second view *('views/groups/groupView.html')* is injected into the **'views/groups/groupBaseView.html'**
- the third goes to the **'views/groups/groupView.html'**

So, the `'views/groups/groupView.html'` will look like this:

```
<div>   
   ...
   <div ui-view="leftcontainer"></div>   
</div>
```

and `'views/groups/groupView.html'` will be:

```
<div>   
   ...
   <div ui-view="rightcontainer"></div>   
</div>
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ISiMe6OvXYkbKoJomOCv?p=preview)

Comment: thanks a lot for making such a complex time so easy. I read your answer then tried it myself and everything went so smoothly.    http://plnkr.co/DcsBaPCyqV5p8waklGda

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have nested "views" attributes. You have to first define a child state and define its view then.

A quick example:

```
.state("a", {
    views: {
        template:"<ui-view></ui-view>"
    }
})
.state("a.b", {
    views: {
        template:"<ui-view></ui-view>"
    }
})
.state("a.b.c", {
    views: {
        template:"<h1>Something</h1>"
    }
})
```

Comment: How to achieve 3 or more level deep `ui-views`?